# ошибка terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument' what(): stoi

Tags: c++

В языке С++ я новичок, нужно было написать код по декодированию файла по методу Шеннона-Фано. При тестирование вылезла такая ошибка, особо не понимаю в чём проблема....

````
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

void decodeFile(const std::string& inputFile, const std::string& keyFile) {
    // Чтение ключа из файла
    std::map<char, int> key;
    std::ifstream keyStream(keyFile);
    if (!keyStream.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Ошибка открытия файла с ключом.\n";
        return;
    }
    
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(keyStream, line)) {
        if (line.empty()) continue;
        char symbol = line[1];
        int code = std::stoi(line.substr(3));
        key[symbol] = code;
    }
    keyStream.close();
    
    // Раскодирование файла
    std::ifstream input(inputFile);
    if (!input.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Ошибка открытия входного файла.\n";
        return;
    }
    
    std::string decodedText;
    std::string encodedLine;
    while (std::getline(input, encodedLine)) {
        for (char encodedSymbol : encodedLine) {
            if (encodedSymbol == ' ') {
                decodedText += ' ';
                continue;
            }
            
            for (const auto& p : key) {
                if (p.second == encodedSymbol) {
                    decodedText += p.first;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        decodedText += '\n';
    }
    input.close();
    
    // Запись раскодированного текста в файл
    std::ofstream output(inputFile + "_decoded.txt");
    if (!output.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Ошибка создания выходного файла.\n";
        return;
    }
    
    output << decodedText;
    output.close();
    
    std::cout << "Раскодирование завершено. Раскодированный текст сохранен в файле " << inputFile << "_decoded.txt.\n";
}

int main() {
    std::string inputFile = "input.txt";
    std::string keyFile = "key.txt";
    
    decodeFile(inputFile, keyFile);
    
    return 0;
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Ну очевидно, что это исключение вызвано функцией `std::stoi()` в строке вашего кода:

```
int code = std::stoi(line.substr(3));
```

В документации к функции читаем:

> If no conversion could be performed, an invalid_argument exception is thrown.

Т.е., если конвертировать строку в число не удалось, то бросается это исключение. Почему не удалось конвертировать? Быть может потому, что переданная в качестве аргумента строка не является числом?

Чтобы прояснить ситуацию, попробуйте обернуть вызов функции `stoi()` в конструкцию `try {} catch` и вывести отладочную информацию:

```
try
{
    int code = std::stoi(line.substr(3));
}
catch (const std::invalid_argument& ia)
{
    std::cerr << "Invalid argument: " << ia.what() << '\n';
    std::cerr << "line == " << line << '\n';
    std::cerr << "line.substr(3) == " << line.substr(3) << '\n';
}
```

Кстати, на будущее. Этот метод отладки ещё называют printf-отладкой. Если не работает программа, вставляете выводы промежуточных переменных с помощью `printf()` или `std::cerr <<` (или `std::cout <<`), и смотрите, что не так. Простая, но мощная штука.

P.S. не особо вчитываясь в ваш код и не зная формата входного файла, вижу по крайней мере одну ошибку: не учитывается возможность выхода за границы строки при вызове `std::string::substr()`, что потенциально может привести к ещё одному исключению: `std::out_of_range`.